# Install Realm by SPM show Uncategorized warning : "Invalid exclude ... File not found"

Tags: swift, realm

I install realm by SPM after the installation I faced a below warning :

[image]

I found the same issue here :

https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/issues/7295

and solution for it, (I don't get it)

https://github.com/realm/realm-swift/pull/7302

How can I fix the warning?

Realm framework version: 10.21.1

Xcode version: 13.2.1

macOS version: macOS 12.1

Comment: The question is a little confusing. It starts by reporting a possible bug but then you say *To solve the issue I just delete all my packages*. Does that mean you resolved the issue or are you asking if that's how to resolve the issue? If the later, did you try it? We build all of our projects using [Cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org) and have little if no issues - they just kind of work. SPM seems to add (IMO) another layer of... complexity... so you may want to try Cocoapods if you can't find a resolution.

Comment: Thanks Jay, install by Cocoapods remove the warning.

Comment: @fdvfarzin using another package manager does NOT solve the initial problem on SPM.

Comment: @RaduUrsache installing realm by cocoapods will remove the warning.

Comment: @fdvfarzin you don't understand my point. here is an example: switching to Linux when Windows misbehaves is not a solution. actually fixing the Windows problem is the solution... i want to use SPM so no, i can't switch to cocoapods.